# How to efficiently turn a column's values into two count columns?

Tags: sql

I have a table of college classes: CLASSES

| StudentID | Class | Sex |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Class 1 | M |
| 2 | Class 1 | F |
| 3 | Class 1 | M |
| 4 | Class 2 | F |
| 5 | Class 2 | F |
| 6 | Class 2 | F |

But I would like a table that shows this:

| Class | M | F |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Class 1 | 2 | 1 |
| Class 2 | 0 | 3 |

How can I make this table without left joining subqueries? Is there a less verbose and/or more efficient way of writing this?

I've tried using regular old joins, like this:

```
select
  class
  ,m.men
  ,f.women
from 
  CLASSES c
left join
  (select class, count(1) men from CLASSES where sex = 'M') m
  on c.class = m.class
left join 
  (select class, count(1) women from CLASSES where sex = 'F') f
  on c.class = f.class
```

I know I can use

```
sum(case when sex = 'M' then 1 else 0 end) M
sum(case when sex = 'F' then 1 else 0 end) F
```

But is there a better way?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid left joins?

Comment: @Reinderien Edited: Less verbose and/or faster run time

Comment: Which RDBMS do you use?

Comment: @JonasMetzler I have no idea even how to find that

Comment: You don't know what DB you use (for example, Oracle DB, Sql Server DB...)?

Comment: No, there's no better way. `case` is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT
    class AS Class,
    COUNT(IF(sex = 'M', 1, NULL)) AS M,
    COUNT(IF(sex = 'F', 1, NULL)) AS F
FROM
    classes
GROUP BY
    class;
```

This may help you, personally prefer to use `IF` in **mysql** database ,Of course you can also use `case`

```sql
SELECT
    class AS Class,
    SUM(CASE WHEN sex = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS M,
    SUM(CASE WHEN sex = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS F
FROM
    classes
GROUP BY
    class;
```

Or to simplify it slightly

```sql
SELECT
    class AS Class,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN sex = 'M' THEN 1 END) AS M,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN sex = 'F' THEN 1 END) AS F
FROM
    classes
GROUP BY
    class;
```

This query uses only one `COUNT` function and two conditional expressions to count the number of boys and girls in each class. The `CASE` statement returns 1 when the gender (sex) is 'M', and returns NULL when it is 'F', and then the `COUNT` function will count the number of non-NULL values

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that you already tried `case`

Comment: No worries, the count(case/if) examples are a good suggestion. Thank you @HuaJFrame

Comment: `IF` - which dbms are you using? Note that OP hasn't specified the dbms, so I would stay ANSI/ISO compliant here, to suit as many products as possible. (Still upvoted.)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think very well, because I only tried it on mysql. Thanks for the reminder and upvote @jarlh

Answer (score 0):

Given your input data:

```sql
create table classes(
    student_id int not null,
    class text not null,
    sex char(1) not null
);

insert into classes(student_id, class, sex) values
(1, 'Class 1', 'M'),
(2, 'Class 1', 'F'),
(3, 'Class 1', 'M'),
(4, 'Class 2', 'F'),
(5, 'Class 2', 'F'),
(6, 'Class 2', 'F');
```

a more useful view is simply

```sql
select class, sex, count(*) as n
from classes
group by class, sex;
```

```
class   sex     n
Class 2     F   3
Class 1     F   1
Class 1     M   2
```

This can then be transformed into the shape you show, but that's not particularly helpful, especially since you would have to accommodate for values of `sex` other than `M` and `F`.

Comment: How would I transform the shape?